# Program type already present: com.register.register.BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have tried to change my package name which differ from library name, but it is still showing the same error.i think there is a problem with my build.gradle, so here is my build.gradle of my app.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'M:/android-storage-master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.register.register"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':storage')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: How did you change you package name?